# Polymer app-storage "app-indexeddb-mirror" not working with Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, indexeddb, polymer-2.x

By simply adding app-indexeddb-mirror to the latest polymer starter kit, I get the following error codes in the Edge (v 14) console:

```
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

Is Edge supported by that element ?

Comment: Not sure what happened with the image upload... Console showed:

Comment: Opening database...

Comment: AppIndexedDBMirrorWorder started

Comment: [Object errorEvent]

Comment: InvalidStateError

Comment: SCRIPT0: InvalidStateError (common-worker-scope.js (48,1))

Comment: Database opened

Comment: ** Note that App IndexedDB Client connecting... and  App IndexedDB Client connected! are missing !

Answer (score 1):

the [app-indexddb-mirror](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-storage/blob/master/app-indexeddb-mirror/app-indexeddb-mirror.html) component uses a shared webworker to sync its data. Since shared webworkers are not yet implemented in [edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/serviceworker/) this is definitly not supported.

Actually the comment on this anwser is right. It does switch to a standardWorker. But these are also in development. So still not Supported

Comment: Not true: "`app-indexeddb-mirror` will prefer SharedWorker if it is available in the browser where the app is running. If SharedWorker is not available, it will attempt to fall back to a standard WebWorker."

Comment: edge has shipped with webworkers since it's very first commit, as they existed back in ie 10